# React+SpringBoot deploy in MultiDocker in ElasticBeantalk ,not able to communicate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I create two separate Docker image for React(port 80) and SpringBoot(port 8080). while running the docker-compose on my local , it is fine working. When I  deploy in MultiDocker in ElasticBeantalk ,not able to communicate.
I follow the link  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html

Comment: React runs in the browser, not in the container. Are you doing some sort of proxying of API requests through the React container or something?

Comment: React application is running from the Docker container and I want react application can talk to Rest api (springboot )  in another docker container. But in the ElasticBeantalk MultiDocker env ,  React Application (Docker 1) -> Resp Api(Springboot Docker 2) ,not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

ok , finally ,got the solution. So I create the one nginx server in which default.conf set the proxy_pass
e.g

```
location /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://servername:8080/api/v1/;
        }
```

And Made some changes in the React application to call the Rest Api.
After that It work in the Elastic Bean talk MultiDocker evn.

For reference link - https://github.com/km2411/flask_template/blob/master/nginx/default.conf